# My first APP, Cordova and iOS

Tags: html, ios, events, cordova, cordova-3

I'm trying to do a simple APP with Phonegap (cordova 3.0.0) on iOS. Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>APP</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }
</script>
</head> 
<body onload="onLoad()">
    HOLA
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.google.es" target="_blank"> PULSAME </a>
    <div id="idi"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing happens. My device never is ready, never shows the alert. I think the problem is the cordova.js, but I can't find the problem (the proyect was created fine and runs).

Any help?

Comment: Nothing in the logs? Does the example work? (The one that just says "Device Ready"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use your onLoad function to attach the listener. Instead just attach the listener, then use your onDeviceReady function as if it is the onLoad. It should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>SmartPol</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }
</script>
</head> 
<body>
    HOLA
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.google.es" target="_blank"> PULSAME </a>
    <div id="idi"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if you want to attach any other event listeners then you can do so after onDeviceReady has fired.

Comment: Yes, that works! Now my another problem is the link, I want open it in another navigator, not in phonegap. i tried target="_blank", target="_system" but nothing works :(

Comment: Do mean like an [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)? Or do you mean like switching local pages?

Comment: I mean, when I click on link,I want open the new page on a new window, outside from phonegap, because I can't return to the previous page.